# Responsive Email Template in Twig file

Tags: symfony, twig

Trying to build a responsive email template in a Twig file. Using Swiftmailer within a Symfony application to send the emails. Two issues I am having so far is the images only show when I view the email on my localhost not when the email is viewed in Gmail, Inbox or Yahoo!

Linking the images using an absolute path (currently). Also, tried a relative path with the same result.

```
<img src="{{ absolute_url(asset('bundles/coreecommerce/images/logo.png')) }}">
```

Problem #2 is include stylesheets. I have some media queries in a stylesheet I am trying to include within a head tag like this.

```
  {% block stylesheets %}
    <link href="{{ asset('bundles/coreecommerce/css/email.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
  {% endblock %}
```

I'm doing something wrong here. Just not sure what? Can you include stylesheets, inline styles for a responsive email in Twig?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Both Gmail, Inbox, and Yahoo will all use external asset blocking for emails to prevent view detection from uniquely generated URLs (e.g. `http://www.malicious.com/spamlink.php?email=bob@hackme.com`.) The way around this is base64 encoding your images into the email, and using inline CSS.

Comment: And by inline CSS, I mean `style` attributes, _not_ `style` tags.

Comment: Would that look like this?                                                                                                                  <img src="data:image/png;base64,{{ absolute_url(asset('bundles/coreecommerce/images/logo.png')) }}">

Comment: Like what? If you're talking about what you've written in your question, no. Not at all.

Answer (score 0):

To inline images in your html mails you should take a look at [this section of the documentation](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html#embedding-inline-media-files).

To show you the example with twig, you can start with something like this:

```
<?php

$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance();

$fileToEmbed = 'a path to image file';

$templateParams = [
    'fileToEmbed' => $message->embed(\Swift_Image::fromPath($fileToEmbed)),
];

// then compose the mail like this
$message
    // set subject etc...
    ->setBody($this->twigTemplating->render('yourMailTemplate.html.twig', $templateParams), 'text/html')
;
```

And then in you twig template you just create a IMG tag with template variable:

```
<img src="{{ fileToEmbed }}">
```

So TL;DR you just need that `$message->embed(\Swift_Image::fromPath($fileToEmbed))` return value to be passed to your mailing template and use it as src attribute.

---

To locate the image file within your bundle you can use `Kernel::locateResource` method like this (assuming that your `logo.png` is located in `CoreEcommerceBundle/Resources/public/images/` directory):

```
$fileToEmbed = $this->kernel->locateResource('@CoreEcommerceBundle/Resources/public/images/logo.png');
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. Now to get my stylesheets included.

Comment: @Brent as it was stated in comments above, you should never link to external CSS in mail templates. Inline them instead. There is a pretty neat tool made my Mailchimp which inlines your `<style>` styles into html tags: http://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/